# Can I programmatically update the values of React bootstrap <Form.Control> after it's been updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, controlled-component

Is it possible to update the value of a React Bootstrap  `<Form.Control>` after it's been edited by a user?

I've created a small Bootstrap form in React with four controlled fields. Details are below. Submission works, but I'd like a way to update the values of various fields programmatically, both to reset the form and to fill in sets of common defaults.

- My code, in which various buttons call `setFormContents`, works until a field is updated. After this, updating the value passed into the `defaultValue` of the `<Form.Control>`. This makes sense, but I'm not sure what is the preferred way to proceed.
- The variables `formContents` and `setFormContents` are assorted with the parent element of `<MyForm>`.

### Details

The state of the form and the associated updating function is provided via `props`

```
define MyForm(props)
 return <Form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onSubmit(props.formContents);
      }}
    >
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="field1">
        <Form.Label>Field 1</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          defaultValue={props.formContents.val1}
          onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
            props.setFormContents({ ...props.formContents, val1: value })
          }
        />
      </Form.Group>
      ///... Other <Form.Group>s
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the update was for all fields. My solution, which is modeled on [this StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632988/how-to-reset-a-react-bootstrap-form-after-submit) was to reset the form before updating it.

1. Create a state that will store reference to the DOM `<form>` element.

```
    const [formDOM, setFormDOM] = useState(null);
```

2. Use the `ref=` property of the `<Form>` element to capture the DOM element. The state will have type `?HTMLFormElement`

```
    <Form
      ref={(form) => props.setFormDOM(form)}
     ...
    >
```

3. Provide this ReactDOM to elements that update the form. Reset the form before any updates.

```
onClick={(e) => {
  if (props.formDOM != null) {
    props.formDOM.reset();
  }
  props.setFormContents(...);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `useRef()` to access your `From.Control` programmatically :

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);

[...]

<Form.Control
     ref={inputRef}
     defaultValue={props.formContents.val1}
     onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
       props.setFormContents({ ...props.formContents, val1: value })
     }
 />
```

And then access to the value :

```
inputRef.current.value = someValue;
```

In your case, in your `onClick` function :

```
onClick={(e) => {
     ...
     inputRef.current.value = "";    
}
```

This approach is less concise because you have to do it on every fields but allows to independently control the content of each From.Control.